# HTML/CSS Text flows outside div trough floating divs

Tags: html, css

**PURPOSE**
Having an editable div in which the text flows in different "simulated" pages, so to obtain an effect like Word. At the moment, I'm interested to have this working in **Chrome** (no crossbrowser compatibility).

**WHAT I'VE DONE**
I've created an editable div (*pagina*) already filled with some text. Inside this div there are 2 divs: *block1* and *block2*.
Block1 is a floating right div that simulates the page height.
Block2 is a floating left div that simulate the space between pages.
The effect I've obtained is a long text "broken" into pages. In my code I've used different background colors to have a better view of the various divs.

**THE PROBLEM**
When I move the cursor at the beginning of a new "page" and I press [return] more times, the new lines are moved at the right side of the above block2 div (the pages sepatator). If I type something, single letters appears in the right side (see screenshot below).

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTMoI.png)

In this Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/n4d2jtd9/4/) you can see my experiments result.

```css
.pagina {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #AAA;
}

div.block1 {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

div.block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pagina">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>

    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>

    <div contenteditable="true" style="width:90px;background-color:#DDD;word-break:break-all;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec libero mi, tempus in tincidunt vitae, aliquet nec nibh. Integer egestas leo vel orci

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**THE QUESTION**
Is there a way to prevent that text effect?

**CONSIDERATIONS**
When you press [enter] inside an editable div, Chrome adds a *div* tag per paragraph (and a *br* tag when you press [enter]+[shift]).
The created "empty" div is always `<div><br></div>`. Having a zero width, the floating div moves this tag to right. I've noticed that if I put a space char inside the div, it works properly. Maybe jQuery can help.

Comment: Why have you tagged javascript and jQuery? Please don't spam tags, only use the relevant tags.

Comment: sorry, my first post

Comment: Then you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting.

Comment: Interesting Question

Answer (score 0):

**New Code**: based on browsers:
working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n4d2jtd9/9/

**HTML**

```
    <body>

        <div  class="pagina">



        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block2"></div>

        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block2"></div>

        <div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="width:90px;background-color:#DDD;word-break:break-all;
        ">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec libero mi, tempus in tincidunt vitae, aliquet nec nibh. Integer egestas leo vel orci

  </div>

</div>

    </body>
```

### **CSS**

```
#editable{white-space:normal}
}

/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    #editable{white-space:pre-line;}
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .selector {-chrome-:only(; 
     #editable{white-space:pre-line;}
  );} 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work... using your fiddle, I continue to have characters in the right side of the floating divs...

Comment: Updated the fiddle at top. Reverify

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I moved the cursor in the "second page", where there text starts with a "t". I positioned the cursor before "t" and I pressed [enter]. In the div above the letters "a" and "m" are appeared in the left side. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aejykl1zfvl6qmp/Senza-titolo-2.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah I have chrome and it doesn't work for me either, still has same issues. If I press enter at the end of ame, it goes off to the side.